# Do expert computer gamers have unusual physiological or mental characteristics?

Tags: neuroscience, performance, video-games, expertise

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any work being done on Perception, Action, and/or Cognition in Video games?](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/20/any-work-being-done-on-perception-action-and-or-cognition-in-video-games)

Are there any research studies that show this?

See [a thread on Quora](http://www.quora.com/Scientific-Research/Are-there-any-research-studies-showing-that-expert-computer-gamers-like-SC2-players-have-unusual-physiological-mental-characteristics) for some initial discussion, but few research articles so far.

> For decades, a different game, chess, has held the exalted position of
>   “the drosophila of cognitive science”—the model organism that
>   scientists could poke and prod to learn what makes experts better than
>   the rest of us. StarCraft 2, however, might be emerging as the rhesus
>   macaque: its added complexity may confound researchers initially, but
>   the answers could ultimately be more telling.   “I can’t think of a
>   cognitive process that’s not involved in StarCraft,” says Mark Blair,
>   a cognitive scientist at Simon Fraser University. “It’s working
>   memory. It’s decision making. It involves very precise motor skills.
>   Everything is important and everything needs to work together.”
>
> Blair, the Simon Fraser University scientist running the SkillCraft
>   project, asked gamers at all ability levels to submit their replay
>   files. He and his colleagues collected more than 4500 files, of which
>   at least 3500 turned out to usable. “What we’ve got is a satellite
>   view of expertise that no one was able to get before,” he says. “We
>   have hundreds of players at the basic levels, then hundreds more at
>   level slightly better, and so on, in 8 different categories of
>   players.” By comparing the techniques and attributes of low-level
>   players with other gamers up the chain of ability, they can start to
>   discern how skills develop—and perhaps, over the long run, identify
>   the most efficient training regimen.
>
> Both Blair and Lewis see parallels between the game and emergency
>   management systems. In a high-stress crisis situation, the people in
>   charge of coordinating a response may find themselves facing competing
>   demands. Alarms might be alerting them to a fire burning in one part
>   of town, a riot breaking out a few streets over, and the contamination
>   of drinking water elsewhere. The mental task of keeping cool and
>   distributing attention among equally urgent activities might closely
>   resemble the core challenge of Starcraft 2. “For emergencies, you
>   don’t get to train eight hours a day. You get two emergencies in your
>   life but you better be good because lives are at stake,” Blair says.
>   “Training in something like Starcraft could be really useful.”