# What is the relationship between computer game performance and measures of ability?

Tags: intelligence, test, measurement, video-games, hci

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any work being done on Perception, Action, and/or Cognition in Video games?](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/20/any-work-being-done-on-perception-action-and-or-cognition-in-video-games)

What is the relationship between computer game performance and measures of ability?

Comment: Related: [Any work being done on Perception, Action, and/or Cognition in Video games?](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/20/21)