# Do action video games have an effect on spatial skills?

Tags: reference-request, plasticity, video-games, spatial-cognition

I've just watched [a TED talk by Daphne Bavelier](http://www.ted.com/talks/daphne_bavelier_your_brain_on_video_games.html), who seems to be [a major researcher on plasticity and video games](http://cms.unige.ch/fapse/people/bavelier/publications/). In it she presents results from a controlled lab study in which participants needed to perform mental rotations (around 14 minutes into the video), before and after having played 10 hours of action video games over a period of 2 weeks. She demonstrates results which show an improvement up to 5 months after having gotten the 'training'.

[image: Improvement of spatial rotations chart]

I'm interested in finding out more about this research and the methodologies it followed. So my first question is whether somebody could link me to the original research.

- Did they take into account learning effects?
- Did they use a control group?

My skepticism comes from [a previous question on video games](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/20/21) in which D. Bavelier is mentioned often. It has gotten some [concerned responses involving methodological flaws](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/529/21).

Comment: For starters, the 3D blocks used (and the concept of mental rotation) [seem to originate from Shepard & Metzler (1971)](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mental-imagery/mental-rotation.html)

Comment: This Bachelor's thesis by Mika Hirvasoja (2004) provides an overview of past research on ["Improving Spatial Skills Through Computer Games"](http://users.jyu.fi/~jorma/kandi/2004/Kandi_Hirvasoja.pdf). I didn't find the particular study demonstrated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concept of [mental rotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mental_rotation) was introduced by Shepard & Metzler (1971). The 3D assemblages of cubes were part of their original experiment. [Vandenburg and Kuse (1978)](http://www.amsciepub.com/doi/abs/10.2466/pms.1978.47.2.599) later developed a paper-and-pencil test based on this prior experiment, named the Vandenberg and Kuse’s Mental Rotation Test (VMRT).

The study which Bavelier most likely refers to is one done by [Feng et al. (2007)](http://dx.doi.org/doi:10.1111/j.1467-9280.2007.01990.x). [[PDF]](http://ixdcth.se.hemsida.eu/courses/2012/ciu185/sites/default/files/files/2007_GenderDifferenceSpatialAbility.pdf)

> In Experiment 2, we compared spatial attention and cognition in men
>   and women before and after 10 hr of action-video-game training. **A
>   control group trained for 10 hr with a non-action game**. [...] In
>   addition, we assessed higher-level spatial abilities using a mental
>   rotation test (MRT; see Fig. 1b). We expected to ﬁnd enhanced MRT
>   performance as a by-product of improvements in spatial attentional
>   capacity after training.

The games played were [Medal of Honor: Pacific Assault](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ur-_GbLgiTI) by the experimental group, and [Ballance, a 3-D puzzle game](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VBp1NtdNCtg) by the control group.

> We had not originally
>   planned a follow-up testing session; however, we were able to contact
>   and retest all 20 subjects after an average interval of about 5 months
>   (16–24 weeks).

Results

> **Both males and females in the experimental group improved, but there
>   was no signiﬁcant change from pretest to posttest in the control group**
>   [...] furthermore, the improvement in the experimental group was larger
>   for females (2.0 to 2.7) than for males (2.9 to 3.2), F(1, 8) 5
>   5.193, prep 5 .87, Z 2 5 .39, and the performance of the females on the posttest was indistinguishable from that of the males in the
>   control group. Although the gender difference on the MRT was not
>   eliminated, its size was much reduced (see Fig. 3, lower left panel).

---

Although not the exact study which Bavelier demonstrated, a study done by [Isabelle D. Cherney (2008)](http://dx.doi.org/DOI:10.1007/s11199-008-9498-z) demonstrates similar results using the VMRT test. A huge section of the paper reviews existing relevant research which might be interesting to look into. The focus of this particular study is to ...

> ... examine whether the type (3-D vs. 2-D) and
>   delivery (massed vs. distributed practice) affect the degree of
>   improvement of males’ and females’ mental rotation performance and how
>   individual differences such as anxiety, prior spatial experiences such
>   as computer game play, and mathematical performance might affect
>   performance. Two existing visuospatial tests, Vandenberg and Kuse’s
>   (1978) mental rotation test and the card rotation test (CRT;
>   Educational Testing Services Sanders et al. 1982) that have shown
>   gender differences and that are of different levels of difficulty,
>   were used.

Tested games were The [3-D Antz© racing computer game](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f4cGpH0QHCk), the [2-D Tetrus© computer game](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R8UehuIYl2c), or several paper-and-pencil logic games.

> An equal number of men and women were then randomly assigned to [the games] for a half hour. Participants returned to the laboratory for
>   another three times for 1 h of practice each. About half of the
>   participants in each practice condition were randomly exposed to
>   either: (a) distributed practice sessions (they completed the three
>   1-h practice sessions over more than 2 weeks) or (b) massed practice
>   sessions (they completed the three 1-h practice sessions within 3
>   days). During the final session, after a half hour of practice,
>   participants completed the two mental rotation tests as a posttest.
>   Participants were exposed to a total of four training hours. They were
>   asked to abstain to play any computer games between the practice
>   sessions.

Practice effect analyses

> Bonferroni adjusted paired sample t-tests on both mental rotation
>   pre-and posttest scores showed that, **for the VMRT there were
>   significant improvements for women, t(30)=−3.6, p=.001, but not for
>   men**

[image: VMRT practice effect results]

<sub>Shepard, R. N., & Metzler, J. (1971). Mental rotation of three-dimensional objects. Science 171, 701-703.

Steven, G. V., & ALLAN, R. (1978). [Mental rotations, a group test of three-dimensional spatial visualization. Perceptual and motor skills](http://www.amsciepub.com/doi/abs/10.2466/pms.1978.47.2.599), 47(2), 599-604.

Cherney, I. D. (2008). [Mom, let me play more computer games: They improve my mental rotation skills.](http://dx.doi.org/DOI:10.1007/s11199-008-9498-z) Sex Roles, 59(11), 776-786.

Feng, J., Spence, I., & Pratt, J. (2007). [Playing an action video game reduces gender differences in spatial cognition.](http://dx.doi.org/doi:10.1111/j.1467-9280.2007.01990.x) Psychological Science, 18(10), 850-855. [[PDF]](http://ixdcth.se.hemsida.eu/courses/2012/ciu185/sites/default/files/files/2007_GenderDifferenceSpatialAbility.pdf)</sub>

Comment: The graph looks like the effect is significant for women..

Comment: @OriesokVlassky That's something that has been measured in many previous studies as well. The effect of practice always seems to have a bigger effect on women. I recall reading about possible explanations e.g. boys when growing up playing with more 'mechanical' toys which have a more positive effect on mental rotation. If you are interested in the gender differences, both referenced papers go into great detail into this issue, but that wasn't what I was after when reading these papers.

Comment: The statistics in the Feng et al. study seem rather weak, I guess. For example, in Experiment 2 no significant interaction between group and time was reported, which normally should be necessary to interpret a group specific group effect, right? Nevertheless, they do interpret the effects of video gaming...

Comment: I just checked out [what the Ballance game looked like](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VBp1NtdNCtg), and I'm a bit puzzled about why they chose this game as a control group now. The pencil-and-paper logic games in the second study seem to be a better control group to me.