# What Quantified Self reserach tools are there for measuring performance while playing videogames?

Tags: methodology, video-games

I've recently became aware that there's a whole [field of quantified self](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantified_Self) - using various methodology to collect data about human performance in an attempt to "quantify" how the human body/brain works. I'm sure a lot of the methodology uses is not rigorous or scientific, but I'm interested nonetheless.

**Are there any third party tools/mods/apps that monitor performance of people playing video games**? I'm looking at cameras that track people's eye motion, [programs that run in background (like rescue time)](https://www.rescuetime.com/tour_new), potentially consumer-grade EEG data or mods that keep logs of games played.

Here are some examples: 
In some strategy games, like starcraft, the concept of **"Actions per minute" - APM** is important, and the user is expected to manage dozens of different unit interactions and commands. It would be interesting to see a plot of APM vs game time vs time of the day.

In some "shooter" video games, especially multiplayer, the concept of "kill to death ratio" is important - how many times a person has killed before being killed. I would expect that there's some kind of a correlation between cognitive performance and ability to stay alive while accomplishing objectives. It would be interesting to see how this is related to the time of day or the person's vital signs.

If there already have been studies done on the subject, I"m interested in who holds/has the data on

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/20/21

Comment: That question has an amazing number of answers, however, I'm looking for something more practical that can run in background and collect data about performance, rather than papers that describe what happens over time of playing

Comment: Performance varies incredibly between genres and even between different tasks in the same game, you can't just make a performance meter for multiple games at once. If you understand the meta-game, the design choices and can identify what each actions are worth, then you have the tools to improve yourself by taking a look back at what you did (using recordings or stats). APM and KDR meters (which are often included in competitive games) could be used to help achieve that goal, but don't count on a standard way to do all this for you.